# How to convert into Date time

Tags: javascript

When the date is passed from my c# to JavaScript it returns the date time as **{4/3/2020 12:00:00 AM}**

[image]

but in JavaScript it is shown as **1585852200000**.

[image]

What is the format that is being used? And how can i convert it back?

Comment: Milliseconds from midnight Jan 1st 1970 UTC, probably. To format it you’ll need to construct a Date object and then use either the Date API to constrict the string, or `Intl.dateTimeFormat`. `new Date(milliseconds)`. I think.

Comment: @BenAston how can convert it back to 4/3/2020 ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the Unix timestamp to DateTime format,

```js
var localDate = new Date(1585852200000).toLocaleDateString("en-US")
console.log(localDate); // only local date

var localTime = new Date(1585852200000).toLocaleTimeString("en-US")
console.log(localTime) // only local time

// local datetime
console.log(new Date(1585852200000).toLocaleString());
```

Comment: According to my string it comes as 
"/Date(1585852200000)/"-How can i only pass the 1585852200000 inside this function?

Comment: `const str = '/Date(1585852200000)/'; const ms = Number(str.match(/\d+/))`

Answer (score 0):

1585852200000 is epoch date.
you can convert it as

> var date = new Date(1585852200000)

```js
console.log(new Date(1585852200000));
```

Comment: According to my string it comes as "/Date(1585852200000)/" as the above image -How can i only pass the 1585852200000 inside this function?

Comment: convert your date to epoch in c# before adding it to response.

Comment: im using MVC type if im doing it how can i do it?

Comment: haven't worked with c#. but there may be a date format method to do it.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative from Shivaji's answer:

When you are passing the date through to JS you could cast it as a string with `DateTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")` seen [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tostring?view=netframework-4.8) on MSDN.

This will keep its integrity visually, if it is just for display purposes, otherwise you will need to re-cast appropriately in JS (in which case use Shivaji's answer).

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript Date's object will return the **DATE object** and it's **POSITION** that is being assigned in your computer. So, when you are working with a date or datetime types, you can use some of the methods that are provided by the `Date` object, such as `getDate()` and `getDay()`. But, a better solution would be to format the `Date` object itself. For example: use the `toString()` or `toUTCString()` methods.

```
var d = new Date();
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d.toString();
```

Reference:

- https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_formats.asp
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date